# android - Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a backup of database and send it by mail
This is my code:

```
public void exportDatabse(Context ctx) throws IOException {
    if(mail.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast errorToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Inserire indirizzo mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        errorToast.show();
    }else {
        email= mail.getText().toString();
        File backupDB = null;
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        String currentDBPath = "//data//" + ctx.getPackageName()
                + "//databases//" + "ILLIBRODELLEBIRRE" + "";

        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        emailIntent.setType("*/*");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[]{email});
        Random r = new Random();
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "DABATASE IL LIBRO DELLE BIRRE");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(currentDB));
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Export database"));
    }
}
```

And it return this error message

android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Help please!